MBS Option Cost Thought Experiment
When one buys a mortgage backed security, one is long a straight bond and short a call option on that bond, with the option cost equaling the Z-Spread - OAS = Option cost.
Let us say that the Z-spread remains constant and that suddenly the option cost - the option that we sold- goes to 0, so that Z-Spread = OAS. Since we sold the option, we should see a tremendous gain on our position, as something we sold went to zero. But in this case OAS actually WIDENS! We would experience negative excess returns to treasuries, not positive. Let me make this concrete:
Time t = 0:
Z-spread = 100
OAS = 50
Time t-1 (Option cost goes to zero):
Z-spread = 100
OAS = 100
OAS widens 50bp: on a 4y duration that is -200bp of return vs treasuries. But I sold the option that went to 0! My intuition says that when something I sold goes to 0 I should gain. What is wrong with my thinking here?

Under the scenario you describe, your OAS loss has offset your option gain.  Seems unlikely in real life, but not difficult to explain.
